# How do I deploy only 1 or 2 dlls for second time deployment of click-once application?

Tags: clickonce

How do I deploy only 1 or 2 dlls for second time deployment of click-once application?

Comment: Tell us a little more about your application and platform.

Comment: You might get a little better mileage out of this site if you read the FAQ first: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce creates a hash for every file being deployed.  When a client starts an application the hashes on their local files are compared to the hashes on the server so it knows what files to download.

I'm guessing you want to deploy a single assembly even though multiple assemblies may have changed.  That's the problem with creating deployments in Visual Studio, you don't have a choice on what goes into your deployment.  If you didn't change any code but simply built a project, that assembly will be deployed because its hash changed.

If you want to have more control over what gets deployed, skip Visual Studio and create your deployments with [MageUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55(VS.80).aspx).  You can start with the files already being deployed, overwrite with the new assemblies you want to deploy, and point Mage at that folder to create the deployment from.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Can you tell me that this MageUI come with visual studio are it is any third party tool i have seen Mage tool which we will use from visual studio command prompt.

Can you explain About MageUI tool?

Comment: Mage comes with a variety of things.  You may already have it.  On my machine it's installed here - "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mageui.exe".  If you don't have it, you can install the Windows SDK to get it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb980924.aspx

Comment: Thanks I got it.l

by using this how can we do the clickonce deployement of only one or two dlls?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  I'm  not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish.